# Extracting F0, jitter and shimmer from an audio file using Python

Tags: python, audio, audio-processing

Recently I got the task: to extract such features as F0(fundamental frequency), Jitter and Shimmer from a given chain of short audio files (around 5-10 sec, a voice singing on one note).
And, unfortunately, I am good for nothing in Audio Signal Processing. Any Python libs to help me do it easy and fast?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using the Praat Software. Praat is a software for audio processing. There is a couple of libraries that allows working with Praat in Python. The best is praat-parselmouth 0.3.2 who allows you to work with prat in your Python enviroment. https://pypi.org/project/praat-parselmouth/

Comment: May the Northern Gods be with you! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Hello there also [librosa](https://librosa.github.io/librosa/) which many example online which well use and also [parseImouth](https://parselmouth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) as said @Adrian and there's too [python_speech_features](https://python-speech-features.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). I'm working in same project.

Comment: thank you very much! Which library, you think, has the edge on acoustic features extraction? Im engaged in recognition of pathological voices', btw, and you? :)

Comment: @Silenos_Chestra  For I'm working on emotions recognition in wav files so I need to extract features. Not easy for me but I'm asking question every where. 
Check this answer on reddit. [Feature extraction which is best PRAAT vs LIBROSA vs OpenSmil](https://www.reddit.com/r/linguistics/comments/bqw93q/feature_extraction_which_is_best_praat_vs_librosa/eocvhjo?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x)

Answer (score 0):

[Omnizart](https://music-and-culture-technology-lab.github.io/) has the capability to transcribe the vocal output to a CSV file that includes the f0. Jitter and shimmer isn't support afaik.